# Accessing kubernetes service from C# docker

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-apiserver

I am trying to access the Kubernetes service using C# docker within kuberentes service.

I have a python docker YAML file and want to create pod using the same YAML programmatically from c# Dotnet core docker that running int the same cluster of python docker. I found Kubernetes api for dotnet core.I created the code for list pods that is below.

```
using System;
using k8s;

namespace simple
{
    internal class PodList
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.InClusterConfig();
            IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Request!");

            var list = client.ListNamespacedPod("default");
            foreach (var item in list.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Metadata.Name);
            }

            if (list.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empty!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code getting error  Forbidden ("Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'").
instead of **InClusterConfig** using **BuildConfigFromConfigFile**  code is working in local environment.Is anythin I missed?

Edited

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-serviceaccount
  namespace: api

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: api
  name: test-role
rules:
    - apiGroups: ["","apps","batch"]
      # "" indicates the core API group
      resources: ["deployments", "namespaces","cronjobs"]
      verbs: ["get", "list", "update", "patch","create"]  
  

  
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-binding
  namespace: api
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: test-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: test-serviceaccount
    namespace: api

---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "4"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-07-04T16:05:43Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    app: test-console
    tier: middle-end
  name: test-console
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-console
      tier: middle-end
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: "2019-07-04T16:05:43Z"
      labels:
        app: test-console
        tier: middle-end
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: test-serviceaccount
      containers:
      - image: test.azurecr.io/tester:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: test-console
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: pull
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      
C# code

  client.CreateNamespacedCronJob(jobmodel, "testnamesapce");
crone job
 'apiVersion': 'batch/v1beta1',
    'kind': 'CronJob',
    'metadata': {
        'creationTimestamp': '2020-08-04T06:29:19Z',
        'name': 'forcaster-cron',
        'namespace': 'testnamesapce'
    },
```

Comment: can your app list pods from "api" namespace? `var list = client.ListNamespacedPod("api");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InClusterConfig` uses the `default` service account of the namespace where you are deploying the pod. By default that service account will not have any [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) which leads to `Forbidden` error.

The reason it works in local environment is because it uses credential from `kubeconfig` file which most of the time is admin credential having root level RBAC permission to the cluster.

You need to define a `Role` and attach that role to the service account using `RoleBinding`

So if you are deploying the pod in `default` namespace then below RBAC should work.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: myrole
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: myrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Once you apply above RBAC you can check permission of the service account using below command

```
kubectl auth can-i list pods --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default -n default
yes
```

Comment: i created role using above yaml (kubectl delete -f tt.yaml) in my default namespace.after i check the command you mentioned is still no.

Comment: i tried this link  in my namespace.and i check with command above you mentioned.its YES.But still i got forbidden error.
 https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/6840#issuecomment-322984003

Comment: The same as Arun, I followed this and while the can-i command returns Yes, I still get Forbidden from within the pod

Comment: I added the ClusterAdmin as suggested in Arun's link and that did the trick. When I get chance to work out the specific permissions required I'll try to remember to update this!